# "spot defective goods" or "check products for defects"

Tags: idiomatic-language, register

Which of the following is more natural?

> - Your job is to check products for defects.
> - Your job is to spot defective goods.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you suppose that one or the other is the more natural of the two?

Comment: I suspect "check products for defects" is the expression typically used in manufacturing.

Comment: Would that make it more "natural", or less "natural"?  Are you wanting to know whether "spot" is too informal for a formal job description, say?

Comment: Yes. Also, is "defective" a bit too formal to go with "spot" (if the latter is indeed informal)? Is "spot" natural in a job description?

Comment: **spot** is a colloquialism, so that if your intention is to write a formal job description, it should not be used. **job** is also something of a colloquialism too. Corporate HR might word the description as follows: *The primary responsibility of this position is to examine products coming off the production line for manufacturing defects.*  The holder of the position might describe his job to a friend by saying *My job is to spot defects*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are "natural", but they are not equally useful.

It is normal to have a situation where somebody takes each "object" and studies it in order to find defects. Therefore the following actually has a practical purpose:

> Your job is to check products for defects.

However, "to spot" is more likely a passive process: you just sit comfortably and look from a distance. If you happen to see a defect, report it. Therefore, there is a high chance to release products as defect-less, while they actually have defects - you just did not spot them.

So your second sentence is correct and sounds "natural", but it has no practical purpose - actually, if you use it in a business, you may be in for some serious trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Either could be used:

"Check goods" suggest a process of taking each item and checking it, in quite a structured way.

"Spot" suggests a less structured approach, searching for defects in multiple ways.